# No suitable 'Program' type for an entry point

Tags: asp.net-core

It seems that a recent update in the nightly RC2 builds has changed the way that programs are started up. Since updating, I'm now presented with an error when running the following command.

```
// "commands": {
//      "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:1287"
// }

dnx --watch web

'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel' does not contain a 'Program' type suitable for an entry point Stopped listening.
```

The Startup.cs compiles and has the follow methods.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IHostingEnvironment env)
    { ... }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    { ... }
}
```

What needs to be done to get the program to start up with the latest [nightly](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext) builds?

Here is an example that reproduces the issue. https://github.com/roydukkey/moist/tree/stackoverflow-34615917

*sdk: v1.0.0-rc2-16357*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [aspnet/Hosting#521](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/521), multiple entry points have been removed.

> Previously we had multiple entry points for web applications including in Hosting (`Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting`), Servers (e.g. `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`) and the the application itself (e.g. `Startup.cs`). We have removed the entry points in Hosting and the servers so the only entry point moving forward is from the application. This will required updates to the `project.json` including setting `emitEntryPoint` to true under `compilationOptions` and setting `commands` to point to the Startup assembly. [aspnet/Announcements#131](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/131)

To solve the issue the `commands` settings needs to point to an assembly instead of listing the, previously valid, server configuration. Additionally, the `emitEntryPoint` setting needs to be enabled. Both these settings are set from the `project.json`.

```
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "commands": {
-       "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
+       "web": "Web"
    }
```

Specific server configurations are now located in the `hosting.json`. The following is just an example configuration.

```
﻿{
    "server": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "server.urls": "http://localhost:1234"
}
```

Please refer to [roydukkey/moist/tree/stackoverflow-34615917](https://github.com/roydukkey/moist/tree/stackoverflow-34615917) in order to view workflow throughout this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `static` class which has a static `Main` method in it. From there, you need to host it. Like below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = WebApplicationConfiguration.GetDefault(args);

        var application = new WebApplicationBuilder()
                    .UseApplicationBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build();

        application.Run();
    }
}
```

Not sure if mandatory but you may need to have the below in your `project.json` as well:

```
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
}
```

In full version:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc2-*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {},
        "dnxcore50": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-*", etc.

Comment: Solution should be the same (unless there is a drastic new change which wouldn't surprise me :D), give this a go and apply your versions.

Comment: 'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'Run' Web.DNX 4.5.1

Comment: hmm, possible that they have moved to dotnet CLI. This might give you an idea as well: https://github.com/davidfowl/dotnetcli-aspnet5/tree/65f454d1a4cea48499d1c01ead6503aa5e244d5d/HelloWeb

Comment: Ah, no. The API has changed in RC2. follow this: https://github.com/davidfowl/dotnetcli-aspnet5/blob/65f454d1a4cea48499d1c01ead6503aa5e244d5d/HelloWeb/Program.cs#L10-L18

Comment: Also, you must install dotnet CLI. I would suspect there will be an update to Visual Studio once RC2 is released. https://github.com/davidfowl/dotnetcli-aspnet5#how-to-run

Comment: @roydukkey no, you don't need dotnet CLI. You can still use DNX tooling. I just checked that. This: https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/codemash-samples/tree/a41a7849628f31201b60faf02fcb9a332c4b7243/rc2/1-hello-world-web runs on DNX and dotnet CLI for example.

Comment: Still can't seem to get it working running `dnx --watch web`. https://github.com/roydukkey/moist/tree/stackoverflow-34615917