# C# Console Application in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem right now, that is, I'm currently trying to create a console application with the newer version of ASP.NET 5 (RC1, CoreCLR), the code is like this below:

```
using System;
public class MyTestClass {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
              Console.Write("Hello StackOverflow");
        }
}
```

When executing `dnx run` I get the following error:

```
does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

So far so good, i've made some research and found that the solution is: you need to have a class called 'Program' as an entry point. 
So to make this work my code is now:

```
using System;
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
          Console.Write("Hello StackOverflow");
    }
}
```

My Final question is: **Why do i have to implement a class Program as an entry point in ASP.NET 5???** If In older versions The first code works perfectly, is this some new functionality of C# 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how ASP.NET 5.0 works, and not C# 6.0.

Based on [Creating a Cross-Platform Console App with DNX](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html)

> The dnx command is used to execute a managed entry point (a
>   Program.Main function) in an assembly. By default, the dnx run command
>   looks in the current directory for the project to run. To specify a
>   different directory, use the –project switch.

Also read MS ASP.NET Announcement on GitHub: [Moving towards unification of entry point semantics with desktop CLR](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/113)

> Support for instantiating of entry point type (Program). The Main
>   method should be public static void Main or public static int Main.

Comment: Thank you very much! It has clarified my mind! Thumbs up!

Comment: @Bruno - If this has answered your question then please mark this as answered.

Comment: This is changing/changed again in RC2, please refer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34615917/4342563), which cites [this github PR](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/521).